# How to append a nested list with another list?

Tags: python, loops, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I'm trying to append a nested list with another list of the same shape, unfortunately so far other questions on this subject on Google and Stackoverflow didn't provide a solution.

```
timesteps = 30
keypoints = pd.read_csv('keypoints_new.csv')
print('Keypoints dataframe shape = ', keypoints.shape)
#print(keypoints)

list_dfs = []
for v in keypoints['MovementID'].unique().tolist():
    new_df = keypoints[keypoints['MovementID'] == v].drop(columns=['Frame #']).as_matrix()
    list_dfs.append(new_df)

#len(list_dfs)) - Amount of different videos:  413  
#len(list_dfs[0])) - Amount of frames for video 1:  250  
#len(list_dfs[1])) - Amount of frames for video 2:  214  
#etc...

def chunks(l, n):
    for i in range(0, len(l), n):
        yield l[i:i+n]

#Cut the list_dfs into chunks based on timesteps
timestep_dfs = []
for i in range(len(list_dfs)):
    df_timesteps = list(chunks(list_dfs[i], timesteps))
    timestep_dfs.append(df_timesteps)

#len(timestep_dfs) - Amount of different videos:  413  
#timesteps - Amount of timesteps:  30  
#len(list_dfs[0]) - Amount of frames for video 1:  250  
#len(timestep_dfs[0]) - Amount of lists within first MovementID in chunks based on timesteps:  9  
#len(timestep_dfs[0][0]) - Amount of data in first list first MovementID:  30  
#len(timestep_dfs[0][-1]) - Length of last list in a MovementID:  10

#Padding of zeros to the remaining list:
for k in range(len(timestep_dfs)):
    if len(timestep_dfs[k][-1]) < timesteps:
        zeros_list = []
        zeros_list = [0] * (len(timestep_dfs[k][0][0])-2)
        zeros_list.append(timestep_dfs[k][0][0][-2])
        zeros_list.append(timestep_dfs[k][0][0][-1])
        zeros_list = np.array(zeros_list)
        test = np.append(timestep_dfs[k][-1], zeros_list, axis=1)

#zeros_list - ['0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' 'Plie' 'Plie_1']
#Length of zeros_list:  77  
#Shape of zeros_list:  (77,)  
#len(timestep_dfs[k][-1][0]) - Length of a row:  77  
#timestep_dfs[k][-1][0].shape - Shape of a row:  (77,)  
#len(timestep_dfs[k][-1]) - Length of last timestep:  10  
#timestep_dfs[k][-1].shape - Shape of last timestep:  (10, 77)
```

So, to summerize... I've got a CSV with keypoints that has a shape of (63564, 78). Within that is a column that describes MovementID, that holds in combination with a various amount of frames (rows) for a specific type of movement which I want to combine in it's own list. So far so good for me, since *list_dfs* gives the preferred output.

But the tricky part now is that I'm cutting each MovementID amount of frames in a set of chunks (based on timesteps). So if I set timesteps to 30 for the first movementID which has 250 frames (rows), it will cut it up in 9 new lists. Where as the last list will contain the remaining list of rows that is less then timesteps.

My expected result should be something like:

```
#Output of timestep_dfs[0] - So the first movementID
#Plie_1 - 250 frames - 77 columns per list:
[[Plie_1 row 1-30],
[Plie_1 row 31-60],
...
[Plie_1 row 211-240]
[Plie_1 row 241-250]]
#Apply the zeroes list:
[Plie_1 row 241-270]
```

The original output/print of that first MovementID is downloadable here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1y6Mvu3id_rnFG4lioHB_b9cwW9zg9houX1WFL1wS488 , if that is better.

In the third code block, where my error arises, I'm trying to append those lists that aren't equal to 30 with a list of zeros. This is required for my Neural Network later on that requires everything to be the same shape, but can ignore 0's.
For now the error arises from the last line of code *test = np.append(timestep_dfs[k][-1], zeros_list, axis=1)*, where I can't seem to append the list with the list of zeros:

> ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions

But as I've printed out, the lists in the list that I'm trying to append and the zeroes list have the same shape.... So why cannot I add it there?

I've also tried np.concatenate, np.colum_stack and just X.append, but each provided their own error/issue and through searches the above should mainly be correct.

I hope the above is understandable and someone is able to recognise my error/mistake!

Comment: could you provide a minimal example with some small arrays and denote what the expected result should be?

Comment: I've added some more context based on your request, hopefully it clears things up a bit.

Comment: the MovementID is a list of numy array with dype=object, thats not how its supposed to be I guess... maybe it helps if you clean that up so you only have float values in one large numpy array.... from there slicing should be easy

Comment: Using python `list`s instead of `np.array`s would allow you to have sublists of different shape.

Comment: @nahtanoj, could you specify on how to best approach this? I'm currently unaware on how to tackle the thing you mentioned.

Comment: @Ardweaden you mean that because it is a np.array, I'm unable to append it due to different shapes? But as I (hopefully) showcased, they should be/are the same size?

Comment: All I can say is, this question would receive a lot more attention and would probably already be solved if it was presented clearly.  Giving just a simplified example would be better. By the way, for `np.append`, both arrays must be of the same shape. Thus, if `timestep_dfs[k][-1]` is 2D, you'd have to pass `[zeros_list]` instead of `zeros_list`.

Comment: @JeBo sure maybe you could edit your question so we have a working example with synthetic input data and your expected result. I guess that would help if still needed